# Not able to fetch the variable's value defined in a module in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have created a dev.tfvars file inside a module and declared some variables inside it. I am trying to fetch this value and assign it to another variable in a different module. This is not working.

Below is the code snippet

```
module "mydemomodule" {
  source = "../modules/dev_env"  // module call
}

resource "aws_instance" "demo" {
    ami = "${module.mydemomodule.AMIS.LINUX_MUMBAI}" // trying to fetch the value 
    region = "${module.mydemomodule.AWS_MUMBAI_REGION}"  // trying to fetch the value 
    instance_type = "${module.mydemomodule.INSTANCE_TYPE}" // trying to fetch the value 
    key_name = "${aws_key_pair.ssshkey.key_name}"
    tags = {
        Name = "${terraform.workspace}_server"
    }
}

dev.tfvars // this file is inside other module
-----------------------------------------------
variable "INSTANCE_TYPE"{
    default = "t2.micro"
}
 
//AWS_REGION      = "us-east-1"
variable "AWS_MUMBAI_REGION"{
    default = "ap-south-1"
}

variable "AWS_SINGAPORE_REGION"{
    default = "us-southeast-1"
}

variable "AMIS" {
     type = map
     default = {
        LINUX_MUMBAI  = "ami-0cca134ec43cf708f"
        UBUNTU_MUMBAI = "ami-07ffb2f4d65357b42"
        LINUX_SGP     = "ami-005835d578c62050d"
        UBUNTU_SGP    = "ami-02045ebddb047018b"
     }
}
```

Error as below while running terraform plan

```
Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 16, in resource "aws_instance" "demo":
│   16:     ami = "${module.mydemomodule.AMIS.LINUX_MUMBAI}"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.mydemomodule is a object
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "AMIS".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on main.tf line 17, in resource "aws_instance" "demo":
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.mydemomodule is a object
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "INSTANCE_TYPE".
╵
```

Comment: You have defined variables instead of outputs, so that is not going to work. Can you add the module code to the question?

Comment: sure ... Below is my module code .. I was just writing a POC while learning and tried to use the below code snippet as a reusable component and hence declared as a module 

variable "INSTANCE_TYPE"{
    default = "t2.micro"
}
 
//AWS_REGION      = "us-east-1"
variable "AWS_MUMBAI_REGION"{
    default = "ap-south-1"
}
Can not add the whole code snippet due to limited characters.

variable "LINUX_USR"{
    default = "ec2-user"
}

Comment: Please add it to the question. If you are providing only variables for a module, than it does not make sense at all.

Comment: Thanks Marko ... but it is already there in my question .

Comment: You cannot reference variable values defined in a child module as if they were accessible outside of that module, because they are not.

Comment: Thanks Marco ... my approach was itself wrong ... thanks for highlighting this. I will change my approach ... Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

A variable in a module is scoped to that module and can not be accessed outside of that module. If you need that value in multiple modules, why don't you define it at the top level, and pass it into all the modules that need it?

If you absolutely need to define the values inside a module, then you will need to add an `output` to that module that outputs the value so that you can access it at the top level.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I tried as suggested by you and still not getting success. below is teh change i made.. In my main.tf i have only below snippet
module "mydemomodule" {
  source = "../modules/dev_env"  // module call based on workspace
}
output "instance_type_mod" {      // instance_ip_addr is the output 
  value = module.mydemomodule.instance_type
}

below snippet in my module file ( dev.tfvars ) 
output "instance_type" {      
  value = "ap-south-1"
}

Comment: Error as below - Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on main.tf line 58, in output "instance_type_mod":
│   58:   value = module.mydemomodule.instance_type
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.mydemomodule is a object
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "instance_type".